# ! ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!

Tags: errors, windows

I just updated my Windows 10 with a couple new security updates. However after rebooting the system none of my .tex will produce a PDF. I leave you the error message:

```
! I can't write on file `letrasgoticas.pdf'.
```

`Please type another file name for output ! Emergency stop. <to be read again> \endgroup \set@typeset@protect l.12 \end{document} *** (job aborted, file error in nonstop mode)`

Comment: miktex? virus protection (avast)?

Comment: Windows: file open?

Comment: files are closed, so I´m going to try with avast

Comment: it was miktek, I updated all the packages and it worked!!

Comment: Could you rename your question with some useful information?

Answer (score 1):

The problem was MiKTeX, an update of all the packages led to a working configuration.